# VB6 and ASP.NET interoperability

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6

I am supporting an ASP.NET app, which is installed on a web server and a VB6 app installed on a different app server.  There is code duplication in the VB6 app and the ASP.NET app.  I want to use some of the code in the ASP.NET app in VB6.  I believe I have three options:

1. Expose the required functionality in an ASP.NET web service.  The VB6 app will consume the web service.
2. Rewrite a small section of the vb6 app in .NET and extend the asp.net app.  This will eliminate some of the code duplication.
3. Setup a class library for the ASP.NET app.  Install the vb6 app on the web server.  Expose the required functionality from the class library in a type library.

Which option is best? I believe option 2 is best.

Comment: Personally I'd go with #1 but I don't know how hard it is to call web services from VB6.  And I'm niased in favor os the Service Oriented Architecture... But I'm not sure this qestion is on-topic.  It's more of a software engineering/design question than a particular coding question.

Comment: @David Stratton, could you describe what you mean by: "And I'm niased in favor os the Service Oriented Architecture."  Thanks.

Comment: I meant "biased".  We started using SOA using web services several years ago, and doing so has made coding simpler, maintenance simpler, and troubleshooting simpler.  Having to change code in one place because the change is at the Web Service level is a heck of a lot easier tan having to recompile the same .dll a hundred places because it's used in several apps.  The trade-off is that if the web service "breaks" hundreds of apps fail, but in our case that's offset by knowing that if hundreds of apps break, we can pin it to the web services. But that's in our corporate environment.

Comment: @David Stratton, are there any performance implications?

Comment: We don't see them.  We actually ran tests comparing using web services to direct SQL calls both to our SQL Server and to our IBM DB2 and counter-intuitively, the web services were faster.  After analysing the packets, it turned out that they made more efficient use of the packets.  The most important consideration is disaster recovery IMO.  Having the web services on a failover cluster if they're mission-critical and need to be back up immediately, or backed up if they can wait for a restore...

Comment: @David Stratton, why did you compare using web services to direct SQL calls? They are two different things.

Comment: @DavidStratton: So now you have to disaster recover your web services **and** your db servers. I'm not sure HA/DR is a strong point in your case.

Comment: HA/DR is all dependent on what deserves that level of protection.  We have some apps, without which, our business cannot operate without serious financial loss.  For those, we do have our DBs and web services clustered, but my point is I'd STILL recommend the SOA route even though we have to have more redundancy.  It's paid off for us countelss times in the few years we've been doing it, and the only additional hassle is the need for extra clusters?  We've saved more $ than our  VM and clustering efforts have cost already.  But again, that's specific to us. It may not apply to others.

Comment: It's all about analyzing your own ROI  What works for me may not work for you and vice-versa.  Which, again, is why I think this question is probably not a good fit for the site, even though it is a good/valid question in general.

Comment: Oh, and @w0051977 - you could always consider option 4 - replace the VB6 app with a completely re-written .NET app.  We've done that as well, as it is harder and harder for us to support VB6 and keep developers that are proficient in it and want to use it. Not that theyre's anything wrong with it...

Comment: @David Stratton, was it time consuming rewriting your VB6 app?

Comment: The first ones, yes.  I made the mistake of trying to use teh upgrade wizard.  Now I don't bther looking at the code except to understand how it worked.  Generally, the "best" way to do things in .NET is completely different than in VB6, so "converting" is a waste of time.  I end up with more bugs than I can stand, or .NET apps that still use ADO Recordsets and other nonsense. I treat each upgrade from VB6 as a completely new app from the ground up, that performs the same funciton as the old VB6 app.

Comment: @David Stratton, Can you post an answer so that I can give credit for your time?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. That leaves your shared, already-tested code on the most modern platform.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer, as it varies for each company and each situation.

As a general rule, I'm very much in favor of using web services where possible, especially if multiple applications are using the same logic for the following reasons:

- If I have to change the logic, I can do it in one place and fix all apps that depend on it
- The same can be said for database connection strings, etc.
- A bug fix can also often be fixed in one place.

  - I've had difficulties with a ***particular*** database that I need to deal with, where the vendor's updates tend to break their .NET adapter.  Twice I had to modify/recompile a ton of apps to resolve this.  Since then, we made it a policy to connect to that DB only via web services, so I'll only need to update ***one*** app in the future.
- When developing mobile apps, the simple fact that we already had all our code in web services makes it that much easier to write apps that are strictly UI and leaving the business/database access logic as-is in existing web services.

All of those are pretty much "Standard" arguments for the SOA approach.

All things considered, my first recommendation, not knowing your specifics would be option #1.

There is a fourth option - a total rewrite of the VB6 app, if it's feasible, and if you can convince those who control the budgets and time allotment. Even with that, you can use the Service Oriented Architecture and split much of the logic into web services.